# How to run Ansible file in Jenkins using Ansible plugin

Tags: jenkins, ansible, jenkins-plugins

[image]

Please look into this error trying to implement the deploy.yml file with ansible plugin which is installed in the jenkins.

In ansible console I can implement the app successfully to the target machine but while same deploy.yml file using in jenkins getting error .

Tried :

1. ssh connection from target and master machine able to connect
2. Add the rsa key/finger print key to the target machine as well as in master controller .
3. From terminal i can able to access target machine as well as can able to deploy any app to any VM but while switched to jenkins ansible plugin getting error.

Comment: I'm thinking that you're using `-k` which means "ask for password", which is what the error message is about.

Comment: Why are you telling us all this, i.e what is your actual question?

Comment: My actual questions is : how to run ansible file in Jenkins using ansible plugin which i have already installed but still getting used that snap error . Question is that which is in snapshot error how to run .

Comment: Hi thanks for your response but i can't find -k in any of my cmd which i have written in .yml or /hosts @schaiba

Comment: @schaiba  Got the solution :

in host/inventory file which is /etc/ansible/hosts [host] 192.XXX.XXX.XXX ansible_user=ubuntu1(target hostname) ansible_become_password=XXXXXXXX(target pwd)

and in .yml part

we have to mentioned - hosts: host become: yes tasks: -name : Update XYZ app script: update.py (in have already written a python script for my process so i have giving same script here in .yml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the solution :

in the inventory file (`/etc/ansible/hosts`) :

```
[host]
192.XXX.XXX.XXX ansible_user=ubuntu1(target hostname) ansible_become_password=XXXXXXXX(target pwd)
```

and in the play we have to set

```
- hosts: host
  become: yes
  tasks:
    -name : Update XYZ app
     script: update.py
```

I have already written a python script for my process so I have giving same script here in .yml

Comment: is that a plain-text password? :(

Comment: @user2818782   use that's the plain pswd which i have stored in the inventory/hosts file but you can put it in vault for the security reasons .For now i have used plain text password which is of my node/target machine not a controller .

Comment: ah. righto. that makes sense :)

Comment: @user2818782  yes ,in case you are getting any error do let me know i will investigate further but for now that above method will work to push any updates to your target machine from controller .

Answer (score 3):

Simple one.
You should either add `ansible_ssh_extra_args="-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no"` to inventory or `disableHostKeyChecking: true` into Jenkins pipeline script (inside ansiblePlaybook block).

Like this:

```
ansiblePlaybook(
  colorized: true,
  installation: 'ansible27'
  inventory: '[hostsfile]'
  playbook: '[playbook]'
  disableHostKeyChecking: true
)
```

Comment: Hi Simth , thanks i will have check and update you hope it will work as i am expecting .

Comment: Got the solution :

in host/inventory file which is /etc/ansible/hosts [host] 192.XXX.XXX.XXX ansible_user=ubuntu1(target hostname) ansible_become_password=XXXXXXXX(target pwd)

and in .yml part

we have to mentioned - hosts: host become: yes tasks: -name : Update XYZ app script: update.py (in have already written a python script for my process so i have giving same script here in .yml)